# How to bring the measure total to rows in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I have a measure in Power BI. How to bring the measure total to rows in power BI ?

[image]

Comment: Hi, I find it. New measure here is CALCULATE([Quantity];ALLSELECTED(MyTableName);KEEPFILTERS(MyAnotherTableName)). Additionally,
I wanted this to be affected by the filter in another table.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ALL table function to compute this:

```
YourNewMeasure = SUMX(ALL(YourTableName),YourTableName[Quantity])
```

Answer (score 0):

Balaji has rightly given the formula to get the total in each row, just wanted to add that now you have to create a column and use the above formula instead of a measure.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @swapnil, If I use this formula, The Total Measure is still equal to The Quantity in rows.

Comment: use ALL instead of ALLSelected, on the tbl which contains your quantity field, as written below CALCULATE([Quantity];ALL(MyTableName);KEEPFILTERS(MyAnotherTableName))